# Scopes in request to AuthServer in OAuth Client implementation

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth, resttemplate

I am working on an assignment, where I have to implement OAuth Client, which will make request to auth server to get access token.

I have implemented it through RestTemplate. Since, I have got some information about the authserver like uri, grant-type, client secret. on the basis of these information I have created a request which returns me proper access token.

But now, requirement is to add **scopes** in request to auth server. can someone help me where this scopes can be added in request as per below code. ? I have tried to add this in header & map. but i get the bad request error.

```
class AuthTokenManager {
    
    
    private ResponseEntity<String> requestToAuthServer(AuthServerInfo authServerInfo) {

        //prepare request
        final HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request =
                new HttpEntity<>(prepareOAuthRequestBody(authServerInfo), prepareOAuthRequestHeader(authServerInfo));

        // requesting auth-server for token
        final ResponseEntity<String> response =
                restTemplate.postForEntity(
                        authServerInfo.getOAuthAccessTokenUri(),
                        request,
                        String.class
                );

        return response;
    }

    private MultiValueMap<String, String> prepareOAuthRequestBody(AuthServerInfo authServerInfo) {
        //prepare request body
        final MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        map.add(GRANT_TYPE, authServerInfo.getOAuthGrantType());
        map.add(CLIENT_ID, authServerInfo.getOAuthClientId());
//        map.add(SCOPE, authServerInfo.getOAuthScopes());
        return map;
    }

    private String prepareEncodedCredentials(AuthServerInfo authServerInfo) {
        //prepare authorization attribute for header.
        final String credentials = authServerInfo.getOAuthClientId() + ":" +
                authServerInfo.getOAuthClientSecret();
        return StringUtils.str(Base64.encodeBase64(StringUtils.bytes(credentials)));
    }

    private HttpHeaders prepareOAuthRequestHeader(AuthServerInfo authServerInfo) {
        // prepare request header
        final HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        headers.add(AUTHORIZATION, BASIC + prepareEncodedCredentials(authServerInfo));
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, URLENCODED);
        headers.setCacheControl(CACHE_CONTROL);
        return headers;
    }

}
```

Comment: Need to check that how scopes are resolved on Auth Server side. Normally, scopes are resolved with space-separated strings.

Comment: well, i have surf on internet and found it is considered as query parameter 
`curl -i -X POST -H Authorization: Basic Mg12YTk2UkEIyIBCrtro1QpIG -H content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded http://myorg-test.apigee.net/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials&scope=A`

so, its clear its gonna be the part of map. but problem is due to comma separated value ie. what if the value of scope is `read,write`

Comment: You need to check by building string by appending scope values with space and by encoding the whole string with Base64. So your value should be encoding of this string **read write**